# How to stich images with ffmpeg when the digit in the frame filename is offset from 0?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i /path/to/file/00%4d.tif test.avi
```

To achieve stitching of videos in this path, however, seemingly due to my filename formatting this command fails to find the files to stitch. When I manually renumber a few to, for example: 001.tif, 002.tif ... this appears to solve the problem (if I adjust the command accordingly).

For reference my files start with ./001599.tif and go up in increments of 1.

Comment: Also, what is the name of this filename-finding scheme if it's common? 00%4d

Is it a standard method worth learning?

Comment: Add `start_number 1599` before `-i`. See http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1

Answer (score 0):

`00%4d` is not 0 padded, your pattern generates `00[1]`, `00[2]`, etc.
`00%04d` gives `00[0001]`, `00[0002]`, etc., which is what you're looking for.

You should just use `%06d`, that gives the already 0 padded numbers: `[000001]`, `[000002]`, etc. 
As you're already starting at `001599`, add `start_number 1599` to your command.